# Make table ID appear as a column and select across all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I've been requested by my superiors to write a query that will search every table in a database (each representative of a road and their total counts of traffic) and take the total counts by hour of motorcycles. Here's what I have so far whilst testing on one table:

```
    WITH
totalCount AS
(
 SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,0,event_time) AS DaySerial,
        DATEPART(dd,event_time) AS theDay,
        DATEDIFF(mm,0,event_time) AS MonthSerial,
        DATEPART(mm,event_time) AS MonthofYear,
        DATEDIFF(hh,0,event_time) AS HourSerial,
        DATEPART(hh,event_time) AS Hour,
        COUNT(*) AS HourlyCount,
        DATEDIFF(yy,0,event_time) AS YearSerial,
        DATEPART(yy,event_time) AS theYear    
   FROM [RUD].dbo.[10011E]
   WHERE length <='1.7'
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(hh,0,event_time), 
           DATEPART(hh,event_time),
           DATEDIFF(dd,0,event_time), 
           DATEPART(dd,event_time),
           DATEDIFF(mm,0,event_time), 
           DATEPART(mm,event_time),
           DATEDIFF(yy,0,event_time), 
           DATEPART(yy,event_time)
)
    SELECT 
        theYear,
        MonthofYear,
        theDay,
        Hour,
        AVG(HourlyCount) AS Avg_Count                   
    FROM 
        totalCount
    GROUP BY 
        theYear,
        MonthofYear,
        theDay,
        Hour
    ORDER BY
        theYear,
        MonthofYear,
        theDay,
        Hour
```

Now I'm sure some of this is redundant or not needed, that's ok for now (I'm new to SQL btw, which is why some of this will be redundant). Basically as it stands, I list the year, month, date, hour and hourly count of motorcycles for one road. Now my two questions:

1. How do I take this query and make it so that it searches across every single table in the RUD database? Do I just need to list them all and UNION them, or is there a quicker way?
2. I realise if I search through every table gathering only the above (year, month, day, hour, hourly count) I will end up with the right data but with no way to distinguish which road all the counts are coming from. Is there a way to select the table ID (in this example, 10011E is the ID, and is the assigned name for a specific road) and place it in a column next to the rows that were selected from it?

If anyone needs clarification on what I mean, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `UNION ALL` and add an additional column for which source.  You'll have to write out each of your tables in this case, but it's perhaps your fastest option:

```
SELECT ID, 'YourTable' TableName
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'YourOtherTable' 
FROM YourOtherTable
....
```

Alternatively, dynamic sql could produce you the same results -- you might not have to type out all your table names, but it comes with a performance hit.